# Solidworks API and Winforms C# swApp (Standalone)

Tags: c#, winforms, solidworks

This is what `solidworks` tells you to do to reference `swApp`, but I keep getting `NullReferenceException` on the line that it is referenced.

Does anyone have any idea why? or How I go about repairing?

Can I reference it later on such as `swApp = ????`

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Save Drawing
    ModelDoc2 swDoc = null;
    int longstatus = 0;
    swDoc = ((ModelDoc2)(swApp.ActiveDoc));
    longstatus = swDoc.SaveAs3(
            @"C:\Engineering\Engineering\SW Automation\Linear Actuator Technology\MLD Series\Prints\Configured Prints\" + 
            textBox1.Text + ".SLDDRW", 0, 2);
}

public SldWorks swApp;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out thanks for the help everyone.

```
SldWorks swApp = null;
swApp = (SldWorks)Activator.CreateInstance(
            Type.GetTypeFromProgID("SldWorks.Application"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere you're going to have to populate swApp.  I don't use SolidWorks so I can't give you the exact code but look in the constructor of their example code. Maybe you can find an example of how swApp is populated there.

Comment: yeah I used their macro recorder to record most of what is going on and the give you  public SldWorks swApp; which does not help me in winforms. I think I will have to figure a way to define it each time I use it.

Comment: That is what I generally do with NX.  You access the Session first then get the work part.  Terminology may be different in SolidWorks. When I use the journal recorder it shows how those variables are initialized though.